# How does one decide if the process if beta decay positive or beta decay negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

I've been given a sample and a daughter product and I'll have to write down the other products of this decay process.
This is a beta decay due to the mass number A being constant in the sample and the daughter product.

Now, I'll have to decide if it's a positive or negative decay. How should I go about doing so?
I do not need answers just a nudge in the right direction

$$\text{}^{27}\text{Si$\to $} ^{27}\text{Al}$$

Comment: Electric charge should be conserved.

Comment: @nephente I think i got it. After the gaining of 1 proton in the daughter's nucleus, if conservation of electric charge holds, then an addition of 1 electron should be introduced.

Comment: @nephente but if charge were to be conserved, it could go either way, that is, either beta plus or beta minus.

Answer (score 0):

Silicon has proton number $Z_\text{Si}=14$, and aluminum has $Z_\text{Al}=13$. So the beta-free decay you have in your question is missing a positive charge on the right side — you must need a $\beta^+$ (and a matter neutrino).

Answer (score 0):

In a nuclear reaction, the number of charges remains $Z$ (almost always) the same, as does the number of nucleons $A$ ($_{Z}^{A}\rm{H}$). E.g. ${\rm{_{1}^{1}H} + \rm{_{0}^{1}n}} \to \rm{_{1}^{2}H}$.

A positron $e^{+}$ aka $\beta^{+}$ has no nucleons ($A = 0$) but a positive charge ($Z = 1$) aka $_{1}^{0}\beta$. Electrons $e^{-}$ aka $\beta^{-}$ have no nucleons but a negative charge $Z = -1$ ($_{-1}^{~~~0}\beta$). With the knowledge we can easily set up and solve an equation:

$$
\begin{align*}
{\rm{_{\color{Red}{14}}^{\color{Blue}{27}}Si}} &\to {\rm{_{\color{Red}{13}}^{\color{Blue}{27}}Al} + {_{\color{Red}{y}}^{\color{Blue}{x}}\beta}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

First let us compare the number of nucleons:
$$
\begin{align*}
\color{Blue}{27} &\to \color{Blue}{27} + \color{Blue}{x}\\
\implies \color{Blue}{x} &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$

First let us compare the number of charges:
$$
\begin{align*}
\color{Red}{14} &\to \color{Red}{13} + \color{Red}{y}\\
\implies \color{Red}{y} &= 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

So:
$$
\begin{align*}
{\rm{_{\color{Red}{14}}^{\color{Blue}{27}}Si}} &\to {\rm{_{\color{Red}{13}}^{\color{Blue}{27}}Al} + {_{\color{Red}{1}}^{\color{Blue}{0}}\beta}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

We know that $_{1}^{0}\beta$  is a positron aka a positron get's realesed.